# can I add a cookie logout to this script?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm using this script to login users and I want to know if I can add a simple cookie that will automatically logout the user after 30 mins of inactivity.

```
...
if($count){
        session_start();
       session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD'] = $mypassword;
        session_write_close();
       header("location: login_success.php");
        }
```

which connects to:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) || !isset($_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD']) ||     (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) == '')) {
            //someone's not logged in
    header("location: index.php"); //it's suppose to actually be there
            exit();
  }
 ?>
```

then to end the session:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

is this possible? this script is off the net, as I don't know a lot about PHP just a bit, so if its difficult I won't bother!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: why is so much new user ask with exclamation mark?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the following command at the top of your script to set the timeout:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60); // for 30 min timeout
```

See the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) for more information. After the time period PHP will automatically garbage collect the sessions.

Comment: wouldn't that automatically log off a user? what if they were doing something?

Comment: It would kill sessions that have been idle for 30 mins.

Comment: ah ok, and where would I put this? at the top of each page?

Comment: Yes or in common include file. You could also set it in your php.ini file to set a server wide timeout like @Pascal MARTIN has mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I'll try just adding it to the top of each page and see how it goes.

Comment: You can reduce the time out for testing so that you can see the results quicker as well.

Comment: i tried ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2*60); to timeout in 2 minutes but nothing happened.

Comment: Ask your host if you have permission to change these settings. They will be able to guide you through the rest of this process.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are automatically expired after a while -- which will cause your inactive user to be logged-out.

For the duration, see the [**`session.gc_maxlifetime`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) directive : you'll want to set it to 1800 seconds.

This can be done in your `php.ini` file, for a server-wide configuration, or using the following line of code :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1800);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['expiry'] = time() + 30 * 60;

if ($_SESSION['expiry'] < time()) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: do I add that to this: <?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) || !isset($_SESSION['SESS_PASSWORD']) ||     (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']) == '')) {
            //someone's not logged in
    header("location: index.php"); //it's suppose to actually be there
            exit();
  }
 ?>